# Customize admin form field in

Tags: forms, 8, theming

I need to customize the aspect of one single field in a editing admin form.
More specifically I want change the height of a multiselect field.
Have I to create complete admin sub-theme containing just a one-line CSS file or there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `hook_form_alter` in a module to attach a the CSS (library) to the form with the needed changes.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use this function for ADMIN forms? If yes, how can I prevent to lose it with further core updates?

Comment: @Gabriele You should look at hook_form_alter in the documentations (api.drupal.org). I'm expecting you know how to make a module understand hooks etc in my answer, as those are needed.

Comment: Ok, I was needing to be sure that my question was not misunderstood. I'm quite new to Drupal, I will read the docs about hook_form_alter carefully. Thanks a lot!